# Convert a JavaScript object's keys with dot notation into an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm receiving objects structured like this example:

```
{name: "Example", fruit.apples: true, "soil.tree.leaf": "nature" }
```

I need a function that can converted it to this:

```
{name: "Example", fruit: { apples: true }, soil: { tree: { leaf: "nature" }}}
```

Comment: That's a syntax error. What exactly do you receive?

Comment: In this situation you'll just have to fix the data at the source, because it's broken.

Comment: I expect the data is fine. If it's delivered as JSON (`'{"name": "Example", "fruit.apples": true, "soil.tree.leaf": "nature" }'`) then it will produce a clean object when it's parsed. The keys can be accessed with square notation.

Comment: My bad, forgot the to make the key a string.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, had tried looking for a similar issue.

Comment: @RobB: Glad to have helped. Also look around the "Linked questions" in the side bar, there are many similar questions